# Edge orientation

Tags: image, matlab

Hi I am trying to get the boundary orientation of an image from the image gradient or canny edge detector as in equation 11 of http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csjason/papers/xxmm-pami2008.pdf

I currently have:

```
 clear all
 Img = imread('littlecircle.png');
 Img = Img(:,:,1);
 Img = double(Img);
 w = size(Img,1);               % width size
 h = size(Img,2);               % height size
 [Ix,Iy] = gradient(Img);       %gradient of image

 i=1;     %iteration for magnetic field loop
 b=0;     %initialize b to zero

 % Magnetic Field
 for pxRow = 1:h % fixed pixel row
 for pxCol = 1:w % fixed pixel column

 for r = 1:h % row of distant pixel
 for c = 1:w % column of distant pixel

 O(c,r) = [-Iy(c,r),Ix(c,r)];      % O(x) = (-1).^lambda(-Iy(x),Ix(x))    --ERROR HERE

 end
 end
 B(i) = {O}; % filling a cell array with results. read below
 i = i+1;
 end
 end
```

However I am getting a subscript indices mismatch when storing into O(c,r). Why is this? and also if anyone thinks there is a better way to do this from the paper then I would love to here it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the canny + orientation detection in one step, by modifying matlab's canny edge detection code or modify an alternative like [this](http://ai.stanford.edu/~mitul/cs223b/canny.m). Canny works by determining the orientation on each step, so you could modify the canny code to also return an orientation map for each pixel.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that the orientation can be obtained from the canny algorithm.I will look into this. would this be easier to do than just simply taking the gradient and calculating the orientation as in equation 11 of the paper I have linked into the question?

Comment: probably... I'm sorry I don't currently have matlab installed to help you debug your code.